# Cauchy sequences: why not a shorter, simpler definition?

Tags: real-analysis, education, math-history, cauchy-sequences

Any ideas on what made

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\text{ such that }m,n \geq n_0 \implies |x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$$

prevail over the equivalent and arguably simpler (for making use of one less variable)
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\text{ such that }n \geq n_0 \implies |x_n-x_{n_0}|<\varepsilon
$$
as the standard definition of a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Because it probably looks like the stronger statement since you can vary $m$.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really an appropriate question for Math SE (it seems pretty opinion-based to me), but, for my money, a sequence is Cauchy if terms, even if they correspond to very different indices, are eventually close together.  That is, if we pick any two terms that are far enough along, they will be close together.  The traditional definition captures that idea, while your proposal seems to say "If we pick an arbitrary term far enough out, all subsequent terms are close to that specified term".  Equivalent... sure, but I think that the emphasis is wrong.

Comment: @XanderHenderson In my mind, the alternative definition doesn't say that at all. It says that _if you go far enough out_, an arbitrary term will be pretty close to all later terms. Sounds to me very much like your "if we go far enough out, any two terms are close together". The "if you go far enough out" part is still very much present in the definition, yet you ignore that to make a sort of straw man interpretation. Also, I interpret this as a question in math history, which I believe is on-topic on this site.

Comment: @Arthur We are limited by the size of the text input box.  "If you pick a term far enough out, all subsequent terms will be close to that term" *feels* different to me than "If you pick a term far enough out, all subsequent terms will be close to each other".  It is a matter of emphasis, not of mathematical "correctness".  But, like I said in my original comment, this is a matter of **opinion**.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the first definition covers the set of points with an $\epsilon$-ball of *diameter* $\epsilon$ and in the second it's *radius* is $\epsilon$. The former allows you to choose any 2 points and then use $\epsilon$ as an upper bound on distance in your proof, rather than $2\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't know about this being onsite or not, but I request whoever answers this question to not give brief explanations, but also allude to why the second definition could have been standardized but was not, and why the first one is standard. Give plenty of examples and make your answer more attractive to users, because as a beginner question from a quite common topic it requires a canonical general answer rather than a short precise one.

Comment: Whether or not this question is on-topic, it should be noted that the History of Science and Mathematics SE also exists. So if this question ends up being stagnant here, it may be wise to transfer it to that SE instead.